# Image/Link is stuck to top-left, even when position is changed

Tags: html, css, position, href

This is my CSS and HTML.

```css
div.musiclink {
  position: relative;
}

a.music {
  width: 258px;
  height: 117px;
  display: block;
  background: deepskyblue url('MUSIC-cursive.png') center top no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

a.music:hover {
  background-image: url('MUSIC-cursive-hover.png');
}

a.store {
  position: relative;
  left: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  background: deeppink url('STORE-cursive.png') center top no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

a.store:hover {
  background-image: url('STORE-cursive-hover.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="musiclink">
  <a href="MUSIC.html" class="music"> </a>
</div>

<div class="storelink">
  <a href="STORE.html" class="store"> </a>
</div>
```

The thing is I positioned everything successfully when I used images instead of href links, but now nothing is working the way I want it to. I don't want the images/links to move when I resize the browser.

Comment: They don't move for me.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the top-left box to move to? Also, do you mean you don't want the boxes to be responsive?

Comment: What I had before was each image was aligned to the center and I moved one to the left and one to the right. I want each link to stay glued to the screen so that resizing the browser doesn't affect it, but whatever position I change the div.class or a.class to it stays in the top left as if it were static.

Comment: So before they automatically aligned center and I used the relative positioning to move them, but now relative means from the top left of the window, so I'm trying to figure out how to change that.